# Could I see a drawing for $x^2 \mapsto 2x$ for this property: The derivative of a differentiable mapping is the linear map of the tangent spaces

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-derivative

I'm reading Vladimir Arnold's differential mechanics textbook and came across this definition and figure:

[image]

[image]

Despite his drawing I still found it vague and hard to understand precisely what he means. Right now I imagine this: The tangent vectors at every point of $y = x^2$ being rotated and translated to make the tangency of $\dot y = 2x$ . However, I would like to see this drawn on in perhaps some simple diagram, and should I be incorrect then a correct drawing on some simple monomial like $x^2$. I am trying to understand exterior and differential forms better, so I feel it is crucial I can visualize this without hallucinating an incorrect intuition.

Comment: Your title is off. The derivative of $f(x)=x^2$ at $x=a$ is what linear map from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Hey Ted, nice to see you again. I was trying to repeat this excerpt: "The derivative of a differentiable mapping $f: M \rightarrow N$ at a point $x \in M$ is the linear map of the tangent spaces $f_{*x}: T M_x \rightarrow T N_{f(x)}$. I would like to see someone knowledgeable about the field apply that definition to some simple curve, preferably a monomial like $x^2.$ Also, I've watched a large number of your videos from differential forms onwards and haven't quite gotten up to your stokes theorem video. Do you ever discuss what is going on with ext. forms in quotients such as: $dy \over dx$?

Comment: Maybe it would help to start by identifying what $M, N, f, x$ are in your example. Next figure out what $T_xM$ and $T_{f(x)}N$ are.  In other words, draw a 1d  version of Arnold’s picture.

Comment: Yes, I can try to guess that M and N are both curves in space and that the tangent space are all tangent vectors to those curves. But no, I can’t fully map it to a 1d version of his picture because I quite frankly don’t even understand what he drew. That’s why I would like to see a simple drawing from someone, it could be in paint honestly

Comment: Draw the graph of $y=x^2$. Pick a fixed $x$ value, say $x=a=3$. The tangent line to $y=x^2$ at $(3,9)$ has slope $2a=6$. We are going to map the tangent space to $\Bbb R$ at $a=3$ to the tangent space to $\Bbb R$ at $f(a)=9$. The unit vector $(1,0)$ (which represents the standard basis vector for the domain, sitting as a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$) maps to the tangent vector $(1,6)$ tangent to the graph, and this vector projects to the vertical vector $(0,6)$. Thus, the "vector" $1\in T\Bbb R_a$ maps to the "vector" $6\in T\Bbb R_{f(a)}$.

Comment: I am including the intermediate step of considering the graph $\phi(x) = \begin{bmatrix}x\\f(x)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x\\x^2\end{bmatrix} $. Note that $d\phi_x = \begin{bmatrix}1\\f'(x)\end{bmatrix}$, and $d\phi_a = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2a\end{bmatrix}$. We then compute $d\phi_a(1) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\6\end{bmatrix}$; projecting onto the $y$-axis gives $df_a(1) = 6$.

Comment: Thank you, but even after reading this comment several times (and trying to draw this with pen) I feel I am hallucinating misinformation. I don't get why a vertical projection is being done at the end, and why $a = 3$ has a tangent vector normalized, but the tangent vector after mapping is not normalized. Likely this interpretation is wrong and hallucinated, which is why I wanted an image. The second entry of $d \phi_a $ being $6$ when evaluated at $1$ instead of $3$ also confuses me. Even a hastily drawn MS paint graph done with a mouse in 20 seconds would work wonders and is all I want.

Comment: Note that you can see the map on the entire tangent space for your example $f(x) := x^2$. In that case, $T\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$.  So, $f_* : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ would be $(x, y) \mapsto (f(x), f'(x)y)$.

Comment: Maybe I should have added $(f(x), f'(x)y) = (x^2, 2xy)$.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt at helping, but this is again completely incoherent to me. Instead of some Bourbakist attempt at explaining this formally or axiomatically, I would really just prefer some quick mouse drawing that shows the linear map between tangent spaces. I am not getting helped by any of these current attempts at answers.

Comment: @Nate, I do not have any Microsoft products, and nor do I want to. Nor do I have Adobe Illustrator anymore, so — despite your whining — I cannot draw the picture you want without a lot of effort. Do you not understand that when you graph a function $f\colon X\to Y$, the graph lives in $X\times Y$ and you can visualize the function by sending $x\in X$ to $(x,f(x))$ in the graph, and then projecting to $Y$, getting $f(x)$. In our case, $X$ and $Y$ are both $\Bbb R$. I put the graph in there to help you visualize. A tangent vector to the graph at $(a,f(a))$ is of the form $(v,df_a(v))$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Then we're effectively looking at a map between oriented 1-manifolds? And the tangent lines aren't normalized, IE their length is important? If it's a map from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then I don't quite know how the choice in lengths of tangent vectors is being evaluated. Is there some ratio analogous to the slope $dy \over dx$ that needs to be obeyed, could I for instance map over tangent spaces with $(2,0) \mapsto (0, 12)$ and treat it as the same result? Since tangent spaces are on a 1-manifold does this become $(2 \mapsto 12)$?

Comment: I'm treating $1$ as the standard basis vector for the one-dimensional vector space $\Bbb R$. But a linear map is determined by its action on *any* basis, right?

Comment: If your map is $f(x) := x^2$, then the linear map from the tangent space at $x = 3$ to the tangent space at $x = 9$ is $y \mapsto 6y$, because $f(3) = 9$ and $f'(3) = 6$.